# Qt application: Failed to load platform plugin “windows”

Tags: c++, qt, runtime-error

I've seen lots of threads scattered about the internet about this particular error message.  All that I have seen have answers that seem to presuppose that the user has heard of something called Qt and wants to do something with Qt.  I got this message while running TeXworks.  TeXworks worked perfectly for me for years until someone being paid to do some maintenance on my computer decided to delete all my files and then recite boilerplate notices to me in a robot voice.

I have never heard of anything called Qt in any other connection and I have no interest in anything called Qt.  I am trying to get TeXworks to function the way it always did.  Is it possible to give an answer to the question of what to do about this that does not presuppose that I came to this with some interest in, and knowledge of, something called Qt?

Comment: Did you try to re-install TeXworks? What steps did you try to fix it?

Comment: I did.  OK, I'll try that again.

Comment: There is [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) application. Just open your `.exe` file with it and it will show all missing `.dll`.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov : Assuming you mean I should drag the miktex-texworks.exe icon into the one for depends.exe, what I see is a list that includes API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTMIE-L1-1-0.DLL and GPSVC.DLL and seven others with a message that says "Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2)."  Next question is: What should I do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, detect what `.dll` files are missing. Download and run [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/). Open (or drag on the main window) application's `.exe` file. In the first level of the dependency tree there will be shown `.dll` files of the application

[image: Dependency Walker screenshot]

A `.dll` with the yellow question mark icon is missing. You should either copy all missing `.dll` files into the application folder or add the folder with `.dll` files into the `PATH` environment variable.